# What is an uncorrelated subquery in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

The MongoDB docs refer to uncorrelated subqueries in their [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries), but I don’t think they ever explain exactly what that term means:

> To perform uncorrelated subqueries between two collections as well as
> allow other join conditions besides a single equality match, the
> $lookup stage has the following syntax:
>
> ```js
>      {
>        from: <collection to join>,
>        let: { <var_1>: <expression>, …, <var_n>: <expression> },
>        pipeline: [ <pipeline to execute on the collection to join> ],
>        as: <output array field>
>      } }
> ```

Can anyone shed some light on exactly what they mean when they say “uncorrelated subquery”?

Comment: This is a standard RDBMS term that is well-defined on the internet.

Comment: That means you can execute non-standard join conditions, like you do in SQL: `inner join table2 t2 on t1.field1=t2.field1 and t1.field2=t2.field2 and t2.field3='FOO' etc.`